# Syntax message in sql

Tags: sql, orm, doctrine

I have a problem i don't realy know how to fix,

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(180) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `roles` json NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
MySQL a répondu : Documentation

#1064 - Erreur de syntaxe près de 'json NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
)' à la ligne 4
```

I took this sql when i exported my database in localhost, but when i try to create the User Table for my site in Production i get this Error message.

I thought it was because je 'Json' format for the 'role' but when i change it to 'array' i still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your mysql version.
Based on mysql site documentation, it say:

```
Prior to MySQL 8.0.13, a JSON column cannot have a non-NULL default value.
```

reference:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

Comment: i'm usinf mysql 5.6 on OVH and i can't change it, so what type of value is good for mysl 5.6 in my sql request? when i use "array" i still get a error